# Record Library missing after creating Records Center

Tags: records-center

After creating a records center site under SharePoint 2013, there is not a record library under site contents, but only the Drop Off Library.

Even in Records Center Management, after clicking - Step 2: Create records libraries. There is no record library listed under Libraries category.

Does it needs to be turned on somewhere? As I see most tutorials for the records center have that by default?

Answer (score 1):

I think I find the issue - "In Place Record Management" need to be active in site collection features